serilog.enrichers.callerinfo how format appsettings.json file to show class method and line of code in log
Does anyone know how I would format an appsettings.json file to use serilog.enrichers.calleinfo to show the class, method, and line of code in the log output?
Below is the WriteTo and Enrich part of serilog in appsettings.json file.
The application is a .Net window servicw
"WriteTo": [
{
   "Name": "File",
   "Args": {
     "path": "Event Log\\OASService.txt",
     "rollingInterval": "Day",
     "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}<s:{SourceContext}>.Method}.{LineNumber}{NewLine}{Exception}",
               "shared": true
   }
 }

],
"Enrich": [
 "FromLogContext",
 "WithMachineName",
 "WithProcessId",
 "WithThreadId",
 {
   "Name": "WithCallerInfo",
   "Args": {
     "includeFileInfo": "true",
     "assemblyPrefix": "OAS.Service.Core.",
     "startingAssembly": "OAS.Service.Core.Services"
   }
 }

]

This question is similar to: How to log the classPath, methodName and lineNumber with Serilog in C#. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
